# How to ensure the generator of Galois extenion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I meet an exercise when I study Galois Theory: Suppose $E/F$ is a finite Galois extension. Suppose $a\in E$ $\\$ is an element fixed only by the
identity automorphism of E, i.e.$\{\phi\in \rm{Aut}(E):\phi(a)=a\}=\{id_E\}$. Then do we have $E=F(a)$?

My idea is: We can easily have $E/F$ is a simple extension by primitive element theorem, i.e.$E=F(b)$ for some $b\in E\setminus F$.

My question is: I do not know how to get $b=a$. Furthermore, if we take $\forall x\in E\setminus F$, can we have $E=F(x)$? I think it might be wrong, can we make it right after adding some condition on $x$? I think it might be right if we ask $x$ is algebraic over F or $x$ is separable.

Appreciating for any idea and suggestion.

Comment: Is $E/F$ a finite extension?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$
Let $n = [E : F] = \lvert\Gal(E/F)\rvert$.

Since the only element of $\Gal(E/F)$ fixing $a$ is the identity, we see that there are $n$ distinct elements in the orbit of $a$ under $\Gal(E/F)$. This is the same as the degree of the extension $E/F$. What can you conclude?

**Edit:** A further hint: Recall that given elements $\alpha, \beta \in E$, there exists $\sigma \in \Gal(E/F)$ with $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$ only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial over $F$.

Comment: Sorry I do not get familiar with galois theory. Suppose $\rm{Gal}(E/F)=\{\phi_1=id_E, \phi_2, ... ,\phi_n \}$, then we can get $\phi_i(a)\neq \phi_j(a), i\neq j$?

Comment: I think I get your point. The minimal polynomial of $a$ is $(x-a)(x-\phi_2(a))···(x-\phi_n(a))$, so we have $[F(a):F]=n$, and we get $E=F(a)$. Am I right?

Comment: @Deemo: To answer the first question: Yes. You don't need Galois theory for that, this is something you would've seen in group theory as well. Note that if $\phi_i(a) = \phi_j(a)$, then composing with inverse of $\phi_j$ gives $(\phi_j^{-1} \circ \phi_i)(a) = a$. But $\phi_j^{-1} \circ \phi_i$ is an element of the Galois group and thus, by hypothesis, must be $\operatorname{id}_E$. Thus, $\phi_i = \phi_j$ and hence, $i = j$.

Comment: @Deemo: For the second question: Yes. The hint implies that $a, \phi_2(a), \ldots, \phi_n(a)$ are all roots of the minimal polynomial of $a$. Since these are all distinct, we see that $[F(a) : F] \ge n$. This forces that $E = F(a)$ since $[E : F] = [E : F(a)][F(a) : F]$.

Comment: Thank you so much.